# How to click on JavaScript link with FF.au3?

Tags: javascript, autoit

Its webpage:
https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-us/home/games

Its link code

```html
<a href="javascript:;" class="register">Sign In</a>
```

I want click on it. This is my code:

```
_FFClick("Sign In", text);
```

or

```
$sObj = _FFXpath("//a[contains(.,'Sign In')]","",9)
_FFClick($sObj)
```

But both not working. Please help me :(

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi friend, I've just updated the question. It's link It's webpage: https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-us/home/games
I want click Sign In and auto login to the page. FF is best. I use IE 8 and seem that the page not work with IE 8. But if FF cannot do, please help me with IE

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
#include <IE.au3>

Local $sUrl[2] = ["https://auth.api.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/login.jsp", "https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-us/home/games"]
Local $hoIE = _IECreate($sUrl[0])
Local $hInputID = _IEGetObjByName($hoIE, "j_username")
Local $hPasswordID = _IEGetObjByName($hoIE, "j_password")
Local $hForm= _IEGetObjById($hoIE, "signInForm")
_IEFormElementSetValue($hInputID, "name")
_IEFormElementSetValue($hPasswordID, "password")
_IEFormSubmit($hForm)
Sleep(1000)
_IENavigate($hoIE, $sUrl[1])
```

Edit: I would rather use winhttp if I was simply doing a login.

Edit2: Here is a winhttp log in to the site. This is the one I would use for a log in and for whatever other request you want to do.
No IE no FF no Opera. No browser at all.

```
#include <IE.au3>
#include "WinHttp.au3"

Local $sUrl[2] = ["https://auth.api.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com", "https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-us/home/games"]
Local Const $sUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)"

Local $hOpen = _WinHttpOpen($sUserAgent)
Local $hConnect = _WinHttpConnect($hOpen, $sUrl[0])

Local $sLoginResult = _WinHttpSimpleFormFill($hConnect, "/login.jsp", _
            "signInForm", _ ; form id
            "signInInput_SignInID", "name", _
            "signInInput_Password", "pass")
            If @error Then MsgBox(0, "", "Error: " & @error & " Extended: " & @extended)

; Close handles
_WinHttpCloseHandle($hConnect)
_WinHttpCloseHandle($hOpen)

ConsoleWrite($sLoginResult & @CRLF) ; This will be site index just for you.
```

Comment: Hi friend, Yes, it's work. But I want go to https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-us/home/games, click Sign In => PSN will show login page => I will fill username + pass to login. Is it possible? I want know how to click on javascript link :)

Comment: It would take a lot to click that button and I am not willing to go that far.

However I would advice you to use the code above. Navigate to that url, login and then navigate to the other url. It is the easiest way.

Comment: The code above cannot solve my problem. Because login, I want add a game to cart, eg https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-us/games/addons/awesomenauts-assemble-loninator-skin/cid=UP4362-CUSA00261_00-AWESOMEDLC333170 So that if you have time, please help me find a way to click on javascript link/button. Thank friend

Comment: If you are gong to input your username and password manually then why the heck you need something to click the Sign In button?

Comment: Hi friend,
Sigin In is first step only. I want to do something as Add to Cart , Place Order but all button is javascript link/function. So that I want click Sign In as a demo to I can do another. 
I want auto create a account too but the step protect by captch so that I must use IE/FF to manual input capcha. 
Now, I want Create Accoount then Add to Cart a game as https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-us/games/addons/awesomenauts-assemble-loninator-skin/cid=UP4362-CUSA00261_00-AWESOMEDLC333170. Please help me

Comment: Captcha breaking is easy but I don't think we can discuss this here. As for the button clicks you want, since they are all JavaScript functions, you don't have to translate the functions. You can run JavaScript functions directly from autoit. What I would suggest is, login with winhttp and save the credentials, then manually create an IE object and navigate to the site.

Comment: Since the credentials are saved, you will be directly logged in when you navigate.